# Dynamically building an AWS image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, build

We want to limit the AMIs our users have access to by providing a "golden image" (one that joins the domain, has our security software, infra software, etc). So we do this by taking an existing AMI in AWS, and building upon it as we normally would.

The issue is that the base AMIs from AWS changes pretty frequently (ie, Microsoft patches, things like that), and that means our golden image is out of date.

Is there a way to provide users access to only images that have all of our software (ie, a 'golden image') but so that it dynamically builds it instead, adding our security/infra software to the base image, and allowing access ONLY to that to the end users of the environment?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to automate that is, when you want to "refresh" the image:

1. Create a new EC2 instance with the newest base windows image
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html
2. Install your stuff:
   Here it would be nice to have puppet/chef/ansible/.../powershell to do it automatically (if possible from the user-data).
3. Create custom AMI from the existing instance:
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-image.html
4. Update the IAM Policy to restrict the instance creation to the new AMi's snapshot: 
   `json
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "Stmt1410544721000",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": [
                   "ec2:RunInstances"
               ],
               "Condition": {
                   "ArnEquals": {
                       "ec2:ParentSnapshot": "arn:aws:ec2:region::snapshot/snapshot-id"
                   }
               },
               "Resource": [
                   "*"
               ]
           }
       ]
   }`

   You can set that policy to a group using the CLI:
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/put-group-policy.html

And all of that could be automated using CloudFormation... i'd recommend you do it by hand at least once and automate step by step.